# Como hago para que mi video se deje de escuchar luego de cerrarlo? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo aplicada en una pagina un video ni bien carga la pagina, es como una especie de pop-up hecho con html y css, el video cuenta con la etiqueta de video y con propiedades en el z-index y position absolute consegui el efecto de pop-up, lo que necesito hacer es que al momento de tocar la cruz en la página que vendria a ser un boton el video se pause o se mutee o se elimine, dado que si alguien pone el video y toca la cruz se sigue escuchando al navegar por la página

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
HTML
<input type="checkbox" id="cerrar">
    <label for="cerrar" id="btnn-cerrar">X</label>
    <div class="modall">
        <div class="contenido">
            <div>
                <video src="video/295737495_141450781577377_7521575527376971401_n.mp4" controls width="500px" height="500px" autoplay muted></video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

CSS
.contenido{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 140px;
}

.modall{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;

    display: flex;

    animation: modal 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

#cerrar {
    display: none;
}

#btnn-cerrar{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

#cerrar + label{
    position: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    z-index: 50;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

    animation: modal 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

#cerrar:checked + label, #cerrar:checked ~ .modall, #cerrar:checked ~ video{
    display: none;
}

@keyframes modal {
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 468px) {
    video{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que tienes una etiqueta `<video></video>` como contenedor del video, agregarías un evento `onclick` al botón de cerrar, para llamar una función de JavaScript que obtenga el id del elemento video y use el método *pause()* sobre ese objeto, puedes tomar como guía este [enlace](https://www.eniun.com/control-reproduccion-video-audio-javascript/)

Comment: muchisimas gracias funciono!